# Derived categories as homotopy categories of model categories

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

Given an abelian category A, is there a model structure on the category of complexes C(A) (or K(A) ("classical" homotopy category)) such that its homotopy category "is" the derived category D(A)?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+chain+complexes).

Comment: Are you interested in the bounded or unbounded derived category?

Comment: This is in fact one of the basic motivating examples that led Quillen to invent model categories, the other being the Quillen equivalence between topological spaces and simplicial sets.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an abelian (or Grothendieck) category, and consider the [injective model structure on the category of cochain complexes $\mathrm{Ch}(\mathbf{A})$](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+chain+complexes#InjectiveStructureOnCochainComplexes). Then the derived category $\mathcal{D}(\mathbf{A})$ is [the homotopy category $\mathrm{Ho}(\mathrm{Ch}(\mathbf{A}))$](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+category+of+chain+complexes) by inverting the weak equivalences.